# Smooth variety as a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I'd like to realize a smooth variety $X$ as a $\mathbb{P}^1$-bundle over some base $S$. Under what conditions can I do that and how can I find an $S$ that would work? How general a scheme can I do this for?

Comment: Welcome new user.  Are you asking when an extremal ray of the $K_X$-negative part of the Mori cone gives a fiber type contraction of relative dimension $1$?